# How can I remove items from a list that are smaller/larger than a user chosen variable in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying to create a function that takes as parameters: a list of items, a list of prices, and two prices. Then return a list containing items in that price range. How do I remove the values outside of the price range?

```
groceries = ['eggs', 'bacon', 'milk']
grocery_prices = [4.99, 6.99, 2.99]

def price_sub_list(items, prices, low, high) :
    new_price_list = prices.remove([low:])
    new_price_list = prices.remove([:high])
    new_list = items.remove(['''equivalent of <low''']:)
    new_list = items.remove(:['''equivalent of >high'''])
    print(new_list)

price_sub_list(groceries, grocery_prices, 3, 5)
```

I want to remove the values outside the price range, then associate the list of groceries to the list of grocery prices and print out the items left in the chosen price range (in this case print out only "eggs")

Comment: Why do you make 2 assignments to `new_price_list`, but never use it?  Why do you overwrite your first assignment to `new_list`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a list of the items whose corresponding price is between `low` and `high`; if that is the case, this will do the job:

```
new_list = [x[0] for x in zip(items, prices) if low <= x[1] and x[1] <= high]
```

Comment: Thank you! My intention wasn't to 'overwrite' the assignment but rather to 'update' it to remove both the end and the beginning. I'm still very new to lists so I'm not entirely familiar with how they work in different situations.